# Javascript CORS - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: javascript, cors, same-origin-policy

I've been working with CORS and encountered the following issue. 
Client complains about no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present, while **they are present**, and **client make the actual POST request** and **receives 200**.

```
function initializeXMLHttpRequest(url) {  //the code that initialize the xhr
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    //set headers
    for (var key in headers) {
        if (headers.hasOwnProperty(key)) {  //filter out inherited properties
            xhr.setRequestHeader(key,headers[key]);
        }
    }

        return xhr;
}
```

[image]

In Chrome

chrome console log

[image: chrome console log]

Chrome OPTIONS request
[image: chrome options]

Chrome POST request
[image: chrome post]

In Firefox

Firefox Console Log
[image: firefox console log]

Firefox OPTIONS request
[image: firefox options]

Firefox POST request
[image: firefox post]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: Access control headers (e.g. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`) need to present in response for both **OPTIONS** and actual **POST**.

Work Flow:

1. **Client** make **OPTIONS** request with those HTTP access headers. (e.g. `Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers`)
2. **Server** respond with those access control headers, allowing access. (e.g. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Expose-Headers, Access-Control-Max-Age, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Headers`)
3. Client makes **POST** request with data.
4. **Server** respond to POST. If `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is NOT present in the server response. Although the POST is successful and shows 200 status code in network tab, `xhr.status` is 0 and `xhr.onerror` will be triggered. And browser would show up the error message.

Header References:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 1):

Value `null` for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` won't do, it has to be **either the origin domain or `*` to allow any origin**.

For more details, [refer to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin).

Comment: I've set it to be origin domain. But localhost have this issue as well. (localhost requesting resources at other domain. )