# Cross-domain JavaScript: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: javascript, jquery

I attempt to make an AJAX HTTP POST to an API another developer built. I use JQuery for that, the API is in PHP. However, I receive the following error in the console:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

My HTML:

```
<form>
  <input id="target" type="text" value="Field 1">
</form>
```

My Javascript/JQuery:

```
$("#target").on("click", checkemail);

function checkemail(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://test.api.planitcommander.nl/funnel_webhooks/emailExists',
    data: JSON.stringify({"email": "rj@xxxx.nl"}),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json'
    })
  .fail (function(data){
    console.log(data);
    })
}
```

**Is there a mistake in my JQuery code, or should I ask the API developer for a solution?**

Seems like the latter going from: [Javascript CORS - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38065756/javascript-cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

Comment: Use chrome extension CORS and enable it then fire API request. You'll get a response.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-toggle/jioikioepegflmdnbocfhgmpmopmjkim?hl=en

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe) and literally dozens of others

Comment: Yep, ask the API developer to enable CORS (if it is actually needed). Else, if you just need to fix this problem during development, check out various chrome extensions like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: Thank you guys! Using the Chrome extension I indeed receive a response now. Do I understand correctly, to make it work outside of deveopment, I still need to ask the API developer to enable CORS?

Comment: It's not always a client-side issue, this is often related to server configuration. Message is clear, "..." is not present on the requested resource, the requested resource is on the server. Several posts exist on SO about that.

Comment: Alright. Thanks again. Solved it on the server side at the API / PHP by allowing / whitelisting the domain from which I send request .

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
function checkemail(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://test.api.planitcommander.nl/funnel_webhooks/emailExists',
    data: JSON.stringify({"email": "rj@xxxx.nl"}),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp'
    })
  .fail (function(data){
    console.log(data);
    })
}
```

Please see https://vverma.net/fetch-any-json-using-jsonp-and-yql.html

Comment: Please add some sort of explanation for your answer