# Javascript CORS request, No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present with 200 status code

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, cors, cross-domain, aws-api-gateway

*I am facing the similar issue as [Javascript CORS - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38065756/javascript-cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present). Unfortunately, I do not understand the answer and want to understand the root cause.*

*High level data flow:*

> Javascript/HTML(Deployed in S3) -> AWS API Gateway. Gateway will
>   return the data back.

*Here is my understanding and the fact:*

> Since my javascript code is in S3, I have to make CORS request to API
>   Gateway to fetch the data. From the code perspective, there is nothing
>   special between CORS request and Same-Origin Request.
>
> Also my code will actually make the request the api gateway and get 200 status code(found it in Network tab - Chrome).
>   However, from the console tab - Chrome I am getting `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '<placeholder>' is therefore not allowed access.`

*JavaScript Code:*

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', URL);
xhr.send();
```

*My Questions:*

> 1. First, From the code perspection, there is nothing special between CORS request and Same-Origin request. Is this correct?
> 2. From my understanding, When making CORS request, we actually make 2 requests. the first one is to make a request to OPTIONS method to make sure we are able to make the actual request. If the server side returns 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'. then the second request can be sent.  Is this correct?
> 3. If the above 1,2 are correct, Do I miss anywhere?  I have already configured the API gateway to allow CORS and tested it. Its returning the response header `{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*","Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"GET,OPTIONS","Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token","Content-Type":"application/json"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, figure this out!

First, The tec knowledge for CORS request is correct from my understanding. Basically, When we need a CORS, then the response header from server side should have

> {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*","Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"GET,OPTIONS","Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token","Content-Type":"application/json"} .

But what happened to my case?

> I am using api gateway as server and enable CORS but I am not aware of the issue that I am integrating my api gateway with lambda func. In this case, Our lambda func must return the response with correct header.

Solution?

> Adding the header mentioned above as the part of the return of lambda func.