# Discord Webhook Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, discord, webhooks

I am sending a Discord webhook request using Javascript, but I keep getting the following errror:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at

> 'WEBHOOK URL'
> from origin 'http://discordfastlist.ml' has been blocked by CORS
> policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
> check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
> requested resource.

I know exactly what this is after googling alot, tried all the solutions I found but nothing seemed to work with Discord webhooks.

The code I am using:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "this is the webhook URL, I am not showing this in the code but it is there", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    'content': "test",
    'username':'Test Webhook',
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be able to negotiate the CORS policy with discord before hand, I think this person had the same trouble with a similar situation. [Javascript CORS - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38065756/javascript-cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

What you really need to do is perform the pre flight responses and attach the correct cors-policy to your request as well from your javascript request